# How to read date from CoreData saved as NSString?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsdate

I have CoreData entity which contain an attribute **dateUpdated** (type `NSString` with format "2013-06-27").

When I want to read this value it returns **nil**.

```
Recipes *oldRecipe;
oldRecipe = [self getRecipeWithCode:i];
NSDateFormatter *dtFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dtFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

NSString *oDate = oldRecipe.dateUpdated; 
//after this oDate is nil
NSDate *oldDate = [dtFormatter dateFromString:oDate];
```

I have already checked value presence in entity with SQL Manager.

How can I correctly do it?

Comment: Either '[self getRecipeWithCode:i];' is returning `nil` or  `oldRecipe.dateUpdated` is `nil` in your core data database.  Use `NSLog()` to determine which and then track down the issue from there.

Comment: One reason for `oldRecipe.dateUpdated` returning `nil` can be that the managed object context in which `oldRecipe` was created does not exist anymore. Do you use multiple contexts?

Comment: @MartinR yes I'm using multiple context, but [self getRecipeWithCode:i] returns non nil data

Comment: @Romowski: A managed object can only live in the context that it was created in. If the context is deallocated then `oldRecipe` will not be `nil`, but accessing the properties will always return nil.

Comment: @MartinR thank you!!! Problem solved by using main context!!! You can post your second answer like an answer to my question and I will accept it )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out in the discussion, the `oldRecipe` object is created in  the 
`getRecipeWithCode` method using a temporary managed object context.

A managed object can only live in the context that it was created in. If the context is deallocated then `oldRecipe` will not be nil, but accessing its properties will always return nil.